# Error in rank(rf$votes[, as.character(clase)]) : subscript out of bounds using AUCRF

Tags: r

I am running AUCRF for feature selection in R and it is throwing an error

```
> object<-AUCRF(target~.,train)
Error in rank(rf$votes[, as.character(clase)]) : subscript out of bounds
 Data "train" is a dataframe,DV-Target is a factor and the all IDVs are integers.
```

How to rectify this error

Here's the code:

```
    library("AUCRF")
    train<-read.csv("train.csv") 
    train$target=factor(train$target)
    train<-data.frame(train)
    object<-AUCRF(target~.,train)
```

I tried to debug the issue and PFB the details:

> options(error=recover)
>   object<-AUCRF(target~.,dev)
>       Error in rank(rf$votes[, as.character(clase)]) : subscript out of bounds

```
Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: AUCRF(target ~ ., dev)
2: AUC.randomForest(fitRF)
3: rank(rf$votes[, as.character(clase)])

Selection: 3
Called from: AUC.randomForest(fitRF)
Browse[1]> ls()                     
[1] "na.last"     "ties.method" "x"          
Browse[1]> x                                 
Error during wrapup: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

What is this error?

Comment: Can you provide the code which is causing the error?

Comment: Edit the question to add details instead of commenting

Answer (score 0):

I guess the train variables are not all binary and factor. 
Definition of the vignette:
data     a data frame containing the variables in the model. Dependent variable must be a binary variable defined as factor and codified as 1 for positives (e.g. cases) and 0 for negatives (e.g. controls).

Answer (score 0):

Your dependent variable *should* be a factor, but it should also be a dichotomous/binary variable--i.e. it should only contain either 1 or 0.